# Lucene query language and numeric range

Tags: lucene, range-query

I'm applying the following Lucene query predicate in order to get all inclusive numbers in 2 to 6 range:

```
value:[2 TO 6]
```

and receive the documents with the following values:

```
567986400000
567986400000
567986400000
536450400000
536450400000
599608800000
536450400000
567986400000
```

I'm interested in the numeric range query and obviously, for example, the `Long` value `567986400000` is not in the range of `[2 TO 6]`. Looks like the range searches are strings and I don't know how to workaround it in mine application for the different numeric values.

How to properly use numeric range queries in Lucene?

Comment: how do you index your document and especially what kind of Field is your field which you use the range query?

Comment: honestly, I do not control this process because I use range queries over the manual index which is built over Lucene in Neo4j database. I have these indexes out of the box and I can only provide the predicate to search in the index.

Comment: well it's pretty important because you need to use specific fields for range queries. will add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve a proper range query you need to use specific defined fields from lucene. See [Field javadoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html)

- IntPoint: int indexed for exact/range queries.
- LongPoint: long indexed for exact/range queries.
- FloatPoint: float indexed for exact/range queries.
- DoublePoint: double indexed for exact/range queries.

So you need to be sure that your field you add this query is one of this types. As you said you use a Neo4j generated lucene index. There has to be an option to create this kind of fields otherwise you're not able to execute proper range queries.