# Neo4j manual/explicit indexes and non-string range queries

Tags: indexing, neo4j, lucene, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I was able to port my Neo4j 3.4.0 application to use manual indexes and APOC procedures instead of queries over the indexles relationship properties. Everything is working like a charm except one last thing - I ran into the issue with non-string Lucene range queries.

They are not working as expected [Lucene query language and numeric range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540788/lucene-query-language-and-numeric-range)

For example:

I'm applying the following Lucene query predicate in order to get all inclusive numbers in `2 to 6` range:

```
value:[2 TO 6]
```

and receive the documents with the following values:

```
567986400000
567986400000
567986400000
536450400000
536450400000
599608800000
536450400000
567986400000
```

that is obviously not the something that was expected.

Is there anything in Neo4j/APOC that I can do in order to get it working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs, it says

'Sorting is done lexicographically'

See 'Range queries' under:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html

You should index the data into, for example a `DoubleDocValuesField` instead of a `StringField`/`TextField` and use a appropriate Lucene query, like `PointRangeQuery`

Comment: I think you mean `DoublePoint`, not `DoubleDocValuesField`. Point fields and DocValues fields work differently.